# Contest winners cryptic clue

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, seasonal

Winners of non-US weekly magazine challenge: end for one side, beginning for second (6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may clue the

> Chiefs or Niners - winners of Superbowl 2020

Wordplay

> [Chi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_(magazine)) - non-US (Italian) weekly magazine
>  e - challeng**e**: end
>  f - **f**or one side (choosing the first side)
>  s - *beginning for* **s**econd

or

> [NIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIN_(magazine))  - non-US (Serbian) weekly magazine
>  e - challeng**e**: end
>  r -  fo**r** one side (choosing the last side)
>  s - *beginning for* **s**econd

Comment: @Rubio - trying more matching wordplay for the second-half.

Comment: Of course now we know what the correct answer is.  That other possibility is, er, just a weird coincidence. ;)

Comment: @Rubio - The latter didn't win.