# Yet another mass-produced Friday cryptic

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]
[Grid in plaintext](https://pastebin.com/qL5sQ1rC)

**Across**
1. Intimidate bovid with hairy tail (7)
5. Intimidate bovid with hairy tail (3)
7/21. String instruments striking first note in southeastern city (3,4)
9. Big football Argentinians held (5)
10. A new plan covering start of rebellion for southern region (9)
11/35/27. Final letter of elderly grandma in a dying resort describing philosophical concept (3,3,4)
12. *(See 15 across)*
13. A mother following Peter, perhaps leading to urban area which is a country's capital (6)
15/12. One servant turned in front of popular former ruler (3,4)
16. Put into motion the framing of defensive scheme (6)
18. A Southeast Asian to draw for the audience (4)
21. *(See 7 across)*
22. Member of a people hiding inside from animals (6)
23. *(See 34 across)*
25. Capital city enters extremely complex turning point (6)
27. *(See 11 across)*
29. Halfhearted effort to make Asian food (3)
32. Moving tin trains are en route (2,7)
33. Be in possession of northern harbour (5)
34/23. Pole reversed material going down the drain for 1970s movement (3,3)
35. *(See 11 across)*
36. Repeated publications rushed to press (7)

**Down**
1. Intimidate bovid with hairy tail (5)
2. Amazing frescos in study of evidence (9)
3. City's corrupt deal with personal assistant (8)
4. Member of a people hiding inside from animals (5)
5. *(See 24 down)*
6. Capital viewed after conflict (6)
7. Hindu narrative bringing up creative work by American (5)
8. Several on the outside react badly to fruit (9)
14. Member of a people hiding inside from animals (4)
15. Shooting up central offices north of New Jersey, with special notice (9)
17. Sport for a jacuzzi, perhaps (4)
19. Save wheat, maybe for periods of hot weather (9)
20. Family relationship brought about the beginning of great monarchy (8)
24/5. A mother following Peter, perhaps leading to urban area which is a country's capital (6,4)
26. Following fanatically to win (2,3)
28. Alt-right gathered around a church table (5)
30. Classes for children covering introduction to nature (5)
31. Recycled from contents of previous editions (4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solved puzzle, with clue explanations:

> [image]

And, in case anyone missed it: there are several Schrödinger clues here (clues that have multiple different solutions, disambiguating by letter count)! 1A, 5A, and 1D are the same; so are 22A, 4D, and 14D; and so are 13A and 24D!

Comment: Only beaten by 30 minutes. That's a victory in my book. (Unless you started well after the puzzle was posted, of course.)

Comment: @LannyStrack (I did -- I only saw the puzzle about 45 minutes after posting.)

Comment: Sorry, @deusovi I only solved one of them. I can't see the grid. See answer below.