# Cryptic Family Reunion: Unclaimed Ignition (Fan-Made)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Inspired by the [Cryptic Family Reunion Series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98054/cryptic-family-reunion) by Jeremy Dover.

The answer to this puzzle is a list of seven thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue may give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin".

The clues are arranged in order but this order is neither by length nor alphabetical.
I've decided to omit the enumeration to make it a little more challenging but will add in if it proves too difficult.

1. Dad to persistently harass and then back off exact guy.
2. "Mom's broken up", said Dory.
3. Sister had nicer fiddle.
4. Walker, for example, on a straight line to get brother.
5. Point to peace-loving aunt.
6. Work and change hoist by about 45 inches for uncle.
7. Grandad's coffee weak after grilling granules in oven initially.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The category is:

> First stanza of "We Didn't Start the Fire" by Billy Joel

The clues:

> are ordered based on their appearance in the song, and Unclaimed Ignition is distinctly a clue for the song title.

```
1. Dad to persistently harass and then back off exact guy.
```

> HARRY TRUMAN = HARRY (harass) + TRU(-e) (exact) + MAN (guy)

```
2. "Mom's broken up", said Dory.
```

> DORIS DAY = SAIDDORY*

```
3. Sister had nicer fiddle.
```

> RED CHINA = HADNICER*

```
4. Walker, for example, on a straight line to get brother.
```

> JOHNNIE RAY = JOHNNIE (Walker) + RAY (straight line)

```
5. Point to peace-loving aunt.
```

> SOUTH PACIFIC = SOUTH (point) + PACIFIC (peace-loving)

```
6. Work and change hoist by about 45 inches for uncle.
```

> WALTER WINCHELL = (W)ork + ALTER (change) + WINCH (hoist) + ELL (45 inches)

```
7. Grandad's coffee weak after grilling granules in oven initially.
```

> JOE DIMAGGIO = JOE (coffee) + DIM (weak) + (A)fter (G)rilling (G)ranules (I)n (O)ven

Comment: Excellent. Your experience shone through here. Well done!