# Cryptic Family Reunion #8

Tags: cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in alphabetical order, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Aunt's harmonic pitch included in inverted key (4)
2. Daughter's own drama (4)
3. Granddad to have a brief snooze (3)
4. Sister will catch, disarm an attacker (5)
5. Daughter returns home (4)
6. Call Prime to get it for Grandma (7)
7. Mom's fury fell on one head after another (7)
8. Uncle drinking up, downing unlimited beers (5)
9. Nephew guarded before a stuttering thanks (4)
10. Daughter's own drama (3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This time all of the clues result in:

> **Currencies of Asian countries**

Like so:

> 1. Aunt's harmonic pitch included in inverted key (4) = **BAHT** (Thailand) = H ([a musical note in some European countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(musical_note))) within TAB (a keyboard key) backwards (inverted).
>
>  2. Daughter's own drama (4) = **DRAM** (Armenia) - 'owned' within the word '**DRAM**a'.
>
>  3. Granddad to have a brief snooze (3) = **KIP** (Laos) - 'a brief snooze'.
>
>  4. Sister will catch, disarm an attacker (5) = **MANAT** (Turkmenistan) - hidden within disar**M AN AT**tacker.
>
>  5. Daughter returns home (4) = **RIAL** (e.g. Iran) - LAIR backwards.
>
>  6. Call Prime to get it for Grandma (7) = **RINGGIT** (Malaysia) = RING (call) + G (prime - i.e. first letter - of **G**et) + IT.
>
>  7. Mom's fury fell on one head after another (7) = **RUFIYAA** (Maldives) - anagram of FURY (fury 'fell') + I ('one' in Roman numerals) + AA (head of **A**fter and **A**nother).
>
>  8. Uncle drinking up, downing unlimited beers (5) = **RUPEE** (e.g. India) - UP in b(**EER**)s backwards ('downing' implying backwards, unlimited implying without limits, i.e. end letters).
>
>  9. Nephew guarded before a stuttering thanks (4) = **TAKA** (Bangladesh) - before 'A', **T**h**A**n**K**s (interpreting 'stuttering' as 'alternating').
>
>  10. Daughter's own drama (3) = **WON** (South/North Korea) - anagram of OWN.

Comment: Excellent, basically crushed it. But can you be more specific with the topic if I tell you that  "Stranger rolls dice" is not in the family?

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah yes, indeed :)

Comment: Perfect! For #1, I was thinking rot13(unezbavp cvgpu) as rot13(gur cvgpu, yvxr svefg npgvba nf va onfronyy, bs unezbavp), which in hindsight was perhaps a bit too stretchy. Thanks for saving me :-)